# mathbb not recognized however mathcal works!

Tags: packages

I get the following error

```
Writing index file thessamp.idx ) (./thessamp.aux)
[0{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap
/pdftex.map}]
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd)
./thessamp.tex:115: Missing } inserted. <inserted text> 
                } l.115 $\mathbb{Z}  \stackrel{\equiv }$
                                        The set of integers \\ ?
```

I am using a template from my school, 
and also, when I try to include the package amsmath, it tells me

```
./thessamp.tex:7: LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    

     l.7 \usepackage{
                amsmath} ?
```

I am guessing this is because the style is old or something .. 
so my question is HOW DO I USE THE mathbb to get me stuff like `$\mathbb{Z}$`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You haven't shown any code but presumably the error message means what it says, and you have used `\usepackage` before `\documentclass` when it is supposed to be used after it.

Comment: Could you please post a link to that template?

Comment: The first error is not caused by `\mathbb`, but probably by `\stackrel` which takes *two* mandatory arguments. I guess you want `\stackrel{a}{\equiv}` (replacing `a` with something else).

Comment: In addition to the other comments, `\mathcal` is built in to LaTeX, `\mathbb` is provided by the `amssymb` package, not `amsmath`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes sorry, i did something stupid after that, the stackerel thing is fine actually (i changed it to \equiv later)

Comment: the template was initially hosted by IISc India, however they have taken down the site now.. one of the comments in the template says it was made in 1991 .. so does that give any information?

Comment: You mean other than raising the probability it was made around 1991 and is therefore rather old? Not sure of the dates here but I think that means it likely predates LaTeX-2e? If the template uses `\documentstyle` rather than `\documentclass` then it is for 2.09 rather than 2e and would need to be updated to be of much use. (You can get things to compile in compatibility mode but it would certainly not make a good template for new documents.)